# Cannot allocate memory, couldn't create child process in cPanel error logs

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, cpanel

I have problems in running my website online, some AJAX request didn't work. On my browser's console tab it says that `POST http://sample.com/query.php?q=getuser 500 Internal Server error`. When I checked my cPanel error logs it says:

```
[Sun Apr 22 16:13:07.069691 2018] [:error] [pid 221236:tid 140196695676672] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client 112.204.160.163:21983] couldn't create child process: /usr/sbin/suphp for /home3/fbacmspr/public_html/index.php, referer: http://sample.com/dashboard
```

Comment: Maybe there is no more memory available?

Comment: Who host your website ? it seems that you don't have enough RAM memory.

Comment: Is there any way to adjust memory limit? Or what should I do?

Comment: Try to modify the memory limit in php.ini, If you don't have an access or it doesn't solve your problem, open a ticket.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.